# Neo4j 3.2.1 from the command line fails with a java error

Tags: java, neo4j

Trying to start Neo4j 3.2.1 from the command line (using Invoke-Neo4j console) fails with a java error. The application starts fine from the desktop icon. The command line option works fine with v 3.2.0

I've raised a bug but has anyone experienced this? I'm running Invoke-Console and get the following Java error - note the highlighted error

---

> Error log: 2017-06-16 11:54:03.206+0000 INFO
>   [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] --- INITIALIZED diagnostics END ---
>   2017-06-16 11:54:03.551+0000 INFO [o.n.b.v.r.WorkerFactory] Bolt
>   Server extension loaded. 2017-06-16 11:54:03.552+0000 INFO
>   [o.n.b.v.r.WorkerFactory] Bolt enabled on 0.0.0.0:7687. 2017-06-16
>   11:54:03.722+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.s.f.RecordFormatSelector] Selected
>   RecordFormat:StandardV3_2[v0.A.8] record format from store
>   D:\Apps\Neo4j CE 3.1.4\data\databases\graph.db 2017-06-16
>   11:54:03.750+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.s.f.RecordFormatSelector] Selected
>   RecordFormat:StandardV3_2[v0.A.8] record format from store
>   D:\Apps\Neo4j CE 3.1.4\data\databases\graph.db 2017-06-16
>   11:54:03.751+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.s.f.RecordFormatSelector] Format not
>   configured. Selected format from the store:
>   RecordFormat:StandardV3_2[v0.A.8] 2017-06-16 11:54:04.474+0000 INFO
>   [o.n.k.i.a.i.IndexingService] IndexingService.init: indexes not
>   specifically mentioned above are ONLINE 2017-06-16 11:54:05.445+0000
>   WARN [o.n.k.NeoStoreDataSource] Exception occurred while starting the
>   datasource. Attempting to close things down. Component
>   'org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.Recovery@e9890a4' failed to initialize.
>   Please see attached cause exception.
>   org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component
>   'org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.Recovery@e9890a4' failed to initialize.
>   Please see attached cause exception. at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:416)
>   at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:62) at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:98) at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:511)
>   at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
>   at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
>   at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:100)
>   at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
>   at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
>   at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:205)
>   at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:124)
>   at
>   org.neo4j.server.CommunityNeoServer.lambda$static$0(CommunityNeoServer.java:58)
>   at
>   org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:89)
>   at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
>   at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
>   at
>   org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:211)
>   at
>   org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:107)
>   at
>   org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:80)
>   at
>   org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint.main(CommunityEntryPoint.java:28)
>   **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized log entry
>   version -10. At position LogPosition{logVersion=0,
>   byteOffset=86193010} and entry version null at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.entry.LogEntryVersion.byVersion(LogEntryVersion.java:162)**
>   at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.entry.VersionAwareLogEntryReader.readLogEntry(VersionAwareLogEntryReader.java:97)
>   at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.LogEntryCursor.next(LogEntryCursor.java:54)
>   at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.LatestCheckPointFinder.find(LatestCheckPointFinder.java:82)
>   at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.PositionToRecoverFrom.apply(PositionToRecoverFrom.java:89)
>   at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.DefaultRecoverySPI.getPositionToRecoverFrom(DefaultRecoverySPI.java:81)
>   at org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.Recovery.init(Recovery.java:80) at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:406)
>   ... 18 more

Comment: Are you using APOC procedures?

Comment: I was able to solve this by re-extracting the entire zip file distribution, earlier I had only added the files under /bin to the Windows distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by re-extracting the entire zip file distribution, earlier I had only added the files under /bin to the Windows distribution

**Summary:** when using the zip file distribution to run neo4j from the command line, use the full zip file distribution